# React: multiple modal and passing props dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a list of items (`ProjectActivityList`), for each item there is the Edit button. Clicking on it opens modal to edit the item. The modal accepts an ID.

```
var ProjectActivities = React.createClass({

    onEditItem: function(id){
        // I want to pass the ID to modal and open it
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
           <div>
               <ProjectActivityList items={this.state.activities} onEdit={this.onEditItem}/>
               <Modal />
           </div>
        )    
    }    
});
```

How I can open the modal passing to it the ID (in `onEditItem`)?

Comment: `this.setState({ currentId: id })` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pass it as a prop and set the state of the current element. By setting the state, a re-render will be performed (if necessary, which it is in this case) and so the Modal will receive the new id.

```
var ProjectActivities = React.createClass({

    onEditItem: function(id){
        // I want to pass the ID to modal and open it
        this.setState({editingId: id});
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
           <div>
               <ProjectActivityList items={this.state.activities} onEdit={this.onEditItem}/>
               <Modal id={this.state.editingId} />
           </div>
        )    
    }    
});
```